# How to add class to first child?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I don't understand, why my code is not working. I need to set the class "selected" to the first `a`

**My code**

```css
.selected {
  color: green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $('.find a:first').addClass('selected');
</script>

<div class="events find">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#0">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#0">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#0">Link 1</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Wrap your code in [document-ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler  `$(function(){ //Add your code })`

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('.find a:first').addClass('selected');
```

```css
.selected {
  color: green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="events find">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#0">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#0">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#0">Link 1</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

It works.

make sure you have jquery loaded and your code is inside document.ready

```
<script>
$(function(){
  $('.find a:first').addClass('selected');
})
</script>
```

fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/gtcjdbab/3/

Comment: I´m so stupid :( Thank you